# Comparing a text string to text output (DHT22)

Tags: arduino-ide, string, dht22

Lately I've received a DHT22 sensor. I've started to create a small temperature and humidity monitor station. One of the things I noticed was if you pulled out the sensor while in use, it displayed "nan". What I wanted to do was if the variable "temp" (for the temperature) equaled "nan", my LCD would display a message. But I keep getting a scope, conversion, and declaring errors. I've tried every variable and a lot of online forums, documentations, and the official Arduino reference site. My code looks like this:

```cpp
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <DHT.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

const int rs = 53, en = 51, d4 = 49, d5 = 52, d6 = 48, d7 = 47;

LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);

#define DHTPIN 27    
#define DHTTYPE DHT22   
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE); 

int chk;
float hum;  
float temp; 

byte bigdot[8] = {
  B00000,
  B00000,
  B00000,
  B01110,
  B01110,
  B01110,
  B00000,
  B00000
};

byte circle[8] = {
  B00110,
  B01001,
  B01001,
  B00110,
  B00000,
  B00000,
  B00000,
  B00000
};

void setup() {
  lcd.createChar(0, bigdot);
  lcd.createChar(1, circle);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  dht.begin();
  do {
  lcd.setCursor(5,1);
  lcd.write(byte(2));
  lcd.setCursor(4,0);
  lcd.print("Loading");
  delay(500);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(7,1);
  lcd.write(byte(2));
  lcd.setCursor(4,0);
  lcd.print("Loading");
  delay(500);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(9,1);
  lcd.write(byte(2));
  lcd.setCursor(4,0);
  lcd.print("Loading");
  delay(500);
  lcd.clear();
  dht.readHumidity();
  dht.readTemperature();
  } while (hum > 90 || temp > 50.00);
  Serial.begin(9600);


}

void loop() {
    hum = dht.readHumidity();
    temp = dht.readTemperature();
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Temp: ");
    lcd.print(temp);
    lcd.write(byte(1));
    lcd.print("C");

    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("RH:   ");
    lcd.print(hum);
    lcd.print("%");

    if (temp == a) {
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.home();
      lcd.print("Whoops! An");
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print("error occured!");
    };
    Serial.print("Humidity: ");
    Serial.print(hum);
    Serial.print(" %, Temp: ");
    Serial.print(temp);
    Serial.println(" Celsius");
    delay(2000); //Delay 2 sec.
 }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please add the full error message to your post

Answer (score 1):

A "float" number has multiple possible states, besides just being a number (It never, though, can be compared to a string):

- A real floating point number
- Infinity
- Something that isn't a valid number

The latter is what you want - that is, the internal data of the float variable doesn't represent a valid number.

There are two functions in the standard math library that deal with this for you.

- Is the number infinity? [`ininf(x)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/isinf)
- Is the number invalid? [`isnan(x)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/isnan)

To use it:

```
if (isnan(temp)) {
    lcd.print("Invalid");
}
```